# Electron app unable to execute a shortcut application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, child-process

```
Uncaught Error: spawn UNKNOWN
at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (VM12 errors:484:5)
at __node_internal_errnoException (VM12 errors:614:12)
at ChildProcess.spawn (VM164 child_process:413:11)
at spawn (VM163 node:child_process:768:9)
at execFile (VM163 node:child_process:351:17)
at t.<computed> (VM155 asar_bundle:2:2218)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (VM161 C:\Users\1\Desktop\Favorite-Games-Library\preload.js:54:11)
```

Im getting this error inside my electron app when im trying to use the execFile function.

this is my code

```
const { execFile } = require("child_process");

  files.forEach((file) => {
    var playBtn = document.createElement("button");
    var listGame = document.createElement("li");
    playBtn.innerText = "Play Game";
    gameListUl.append(listGame);
    gameListUl.append(playBtn);
    listGame.innerText = file.toString().replace(".lnk", "");
    playBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(`click ${file}`);
      execFile(`./MyFavoriteGames/${file}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
          return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
          console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
          return;
        }
        console.log("stdout: ", stdout);
      });
    });
  });
```

im trying to launch a .lnk file which is a shortcut to an application n run into that error im unsure why

Comment: Double-check the file path you are passing to the execFile function. Make sure it is correct and points to the actual executable file and not just the shortcut (.lnk file).

Comment: Awesome thanks it works when launching .exe files. Do you happen to know why the shortcut files (.lnk) cant be executed using execFile? thanks again

Comment: I found that electron has a built in method that helped me execute the shortcut by getting its target and using that with execFile thanks for your help! https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/shell#shellreadshortcutlinkshortcutpath-windows